# ActiveAdmin - generate link to index, with filter preset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In an ActiveAdmin page, I would like to include a link to a list of related resources.  For example, given that a

- Site `has_many` Sections and,
- Section `belongs_to` a Site (in my ActiveRecord models),

I would like my Site's show page to include a link to Sections within the site, which would go to the Section index page, with the Site filter preset.

#### Note that

- I do **not** want to use ActiveAdmin's `belongs_to` function;
- I don't want nested resources for a number of reasons (depth of nesting > 2, as well as usability concerns).

**What I want is to generate a URL similar to the one ActiveAdmin generates if I first go to the Sections index page and then filter by Site.**

The query parameter list generated by ActiveAdmin's filtering feature is pretty crazy; is there a helper method I could use to achieve this goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

I use this syntax:

```
link_to "Section", admin_sections_path(q: { site_id_eq: site.id })
```

Comment: Much better solution than jgshurts's answer

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 21):

I worked out a reasonably satisfactory solution after poking around in meta_search for a bit.  Syntax is a bit clunky, but it does the trick.

```
index do
  ...
  column "Sections" do |site|
  link_to "Sections (#{site.sections.count})", :controller => "sections", :action => "index", 'q[site_id_eq]' => "#{site.id}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: As an additional note this can work with HABTM relationships too. The `'q[site_id_eq]'` section needs to be pluralized so something like this: `'q[sites_id_eq]'`

Answer (score 3):

As jgshurts pointed out, the trick is identifying that `q[site_id_eq]` query parameter.

However, if you don't like the clunky syntax, you can also just use a path helper:

```
link_to "Sections (#{site.sections.count})", admin_sections_path('q[site_id_eq]' => site.id)
```

The [UrlHelper#link_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) shows additional examples of this.

Answer (score 3):

> `#auto_link(resource, content = display_name(resource)) ⇒ Object`
>
> Automatically links objects to their resource controllers. If the
>   resource has not been registered, a string representation of the
>   object is returned.
>
> The default content in the link is returned from
>   `ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers::DisplayHelper#display_name`
>
> You can pass in the content to display
>
> eg: `auto_link(@post, "My Link")`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Girl do
  index do
    selectable_column

    column :name do |girl|
      auto_link(girl, girl.name)
    end

    column :email
    column :created_at
    actions
  end
```

Useful-link: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/ViewHelpers/AutoLinkHelper

> **Note:** This is tested with ActiveAdmin (**v1.1.0** and **2.0.0.alpha**)
>   Hope this works with other version as well. Please update this answer if you are sure it works with other versions you know.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - the asker wanted to know how to prefill the filters on a resource's list page, not how to link to a specific resource.